# How to create an "if" statement based on timer

Tags: swift, if-statement, timer, collectionview

I have a Timer in my ViewController, along with a collection view.

I want to run an `if` statement based on the timer that affects something in the collection view.

However, when I put the statement in the collection view with the cell, it does not run. It's as if the timer object is static.
I tried putting the timer inside the collection view, however this raised an error about "Timer needing to be a top level object and not a local one".

This is my code:

```
@objc func timerElapsed() {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(seconds)"
        if seconds <= 0 {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.yellowSquare.image = cellImages[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your timer?

Comment: Hi @Rob I have the following in my ViewDidLoad - timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerElapsed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: I'd have to see the exact error message. Also, make sure you you add any other code you think may be helpful. Lastly, don't post code in comments. Update your post if necessary.